# SQL type window functions in R (preferably dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the R dplyr equivalent to SQL Server's window functions which allow a program to find `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX` based on some grouping but without reducing the number of rows return.

In SQL Server they would be written as shown by the example below:

```
SELECT
    Account,
     Item_Code,
     Views,
     COUNT( Views ) OVER (PARTITION BY Account, Item_Code),
     SUM( Views ) OVER (PARTITION BY Account, Item_Code),
     MIN( Views ) OVER (PARTITION BY Account, Item_Code),
     MAX( Views ) OVER (PARTITION BY Account, Item_Code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group_by %>% mutate` in `dplyr` for this task, for your case, since you are summarizing the same column for multiple stats, you can use `mutate_at` to simplify this, (*assume your data frame is called `df`*):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Account, Item_Code) %>% 
    mutate_at('Views', funs(cnt = sum(!is.na(.)), sum, min, max))
```

Comment: Does this mean that `dplyr`'s `group_by` is *very* different from SQL's `GROUP BY`? In SQL, confusing `GROUP BY` with `PARTITION BY` is a rookie mistake, but you seem to be saying that it's the correct move in `dplyr`.